# Get num of days between two dates, keep num of days the same when date is changed

Tags: vb.net

User wants to edit start date. Days between start date and end date must always be the same.

For example

Start Date is originally 28/07/2014 and End Date is 01/08/2014

The dates are 4 days apart

User changes start date to 01/06/2014

End Date must now be 05/06/2014

Having difficulty wrapping my head around this logic.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use the `DateTime` methods like `Date.AddDays` or even better: `TimeSpan`:

```
Dim timeSpanBetween = endDate - startDate

startDate = New Date(2014, 6, 1)
endDate = startDate.Add(timeSpanBetween)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two aspects to this:

**Working out the number of days between two dates**

Personally, I'd use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) API for this, but you could still use the BCL's `DateTime` type - subtract one `DateTime` from the other to get a `TimeSpan`, and then use [`TimeSpan.TotalDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Then convert the result to an integer. (You'll need to make sure they really are just dates, to avoid getting a fraction of a day.) You could even just keep the `TimeSpan` if you wanted to.

**Adjusting one date based on another**

If you know how many days you want to keep the two apart, you just need to use `DateTime.AddDays` appropriately. For example, if `startDate` has changed:

```
endDate = startDate.AddDays(days)
```

And if `endDate` has changed:

```
startDate = endDate.AddDays(-days)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try these solutions

Answer (score 1):

```
   ' global declaration
   Dim d1, d2 As Date
   d1 = CDate("28/07/2014")
   d2 = CDate("01/08/2014")

   ' function to find the date difference
   public sub date_difference(d1 as date,d2 as date)
   MsgBox((d2 - d1).TotalDays)
   end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Take two datetimepicker dtp_start_date & dtp_end_date.
Take one numerical updown for gap between days nm_days

```
Public Class Form1
Dim start_date As New Date
Dim end_date As New Date

Dim main_load As Boolean
Private Sub dtp_start_date_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtp_start_date.ValueChanged
    If main_load = True Then
        Try
            start_date = dtp_start_date.Value

            end_date = start_date.AddDays(nm_days.Value)
            dtp_end_date.Value = end_date
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    main_load = True
    start_date = dtp_start_date.Value
    end_date = dtp_end_date.Value
End Sub

End Class
```